# (Python) Efficient way of extract diagonal block part of (AB) without doing matrix multiplication AB

Tags: python, matrix, linear-algebra

Suppose A is 1000x50 matrix and B is a 50x100 matrix. Then AB is a matrix of size 1000x100. I'm doing a task which tries to get the diagonal block (actually column vectors on the diagonal) of AB. Specifically, I'd like to extract A[0:10,0],A[10:20,1],A[20:30,2],...,A[990:1000,99].

However, I would like to avoid calculating AB. I tried "for loop" in columns of AB but it is very slow. Is there any other efficient way to implement this?

Comment: you could try to calculate just the blocks you need instead of the whole matrix

Comment: @NicoCaldo, yes that's what I did by using "for loop" in columns of AB.

Comment: it seems the fastest way is to actually calculate the whole AxB and to take the blocks you need. [Numpy matmul](https://sanjayasubedi.com.np/python/efficient-matrix-multiplication-in-python/) is pretty efficient